# How do I create a service properly in Startup.cs? Could not create an instance of type Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I get this error when the constructor is being visited after a POST (during the GET there is no issue).

> {"Could not create an instance of type 'MyWebsite.Website.Main.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginWith2faModel+IInputModel'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.

In my `StartUp.cs` I have clearly included a `Transient Service` for the interface creating an instance of the InputModel. I simply cannot understand why I am getting that error. Is it because both the `interface` and `class` are defined in my LoginWith2faModel class?
I ask that because in another project I have a setup similar to this and have had no issues. Again, I have a constructor which takes an `interface` and I pass a concrete implementation of the `interface` to that class and initialise it in the constructor. The only differences between this and that is asp.net core's DI. Any help is much appreciated!

#### Startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<LoginWith2faModel.InputModel>();
//previously I had the above set to:
//services.AddTransient<LoginWith2faModel.IInputModel,LoginWith2faModel.InputModel>();
```

#### LoginWith2faModel.cs

```
private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
private readonly ILogger<LoginWith2faModel> _logger;
public LoginWith2faModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginWith2faModel> logger, IInputModel inputModel)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _logger = logger;
    Input = inputModel;
}

[BindProperty]
public IInputModel Input { get; set; }
public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
public interface IInputModel
{
    string TwoFactorCode { get; set; }
    bool RememberMachine { get; set; }
}

public class InputModel : IInputModel
{
    public string TwoFactorCode { get; set; }
    public bool RememberMachine { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does the error page look like?

Comment: Change `public IInputModel Input { get; set; }` to use the concrete type ... `public InputModel Input { get; set; }`

Comment: I tried that earlier @phuzi. After which I would also have to change the constructor parameter type to `InputModel` because of a type mismatch error. But i completely understand you, it SHOULD work. Even when I create a new property of type `IInputModel` and instantiate it to a new `InputModel` it throws no errors! Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is that binding cannot instantiate `IInputModel`. You should really use a separate view model with the concrete type, that you can easily map back to the underlying model.

Comment: @steve This was a while ago. Did you get 2FA sorted out? I'm trying to use current samples and having a hard time...